# When can the following sequence will converge to a finite limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_{n} \to 0$. I am interested in knowing when can the following sequence will converge to a finite limit:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left\{\,{x_{i} \over 1 + i\log\left(\, i\,\right)}\,
\prod_{k = i}^{n - 1}\left[\, 1 +
\frac{1}{1 + \left(\, k + 1\,\right)
\log\left(\, k + 1\,\right)}\,\right]\,\right\}
$$

Comment: Why are you interested in this and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $x_i$ are, presumably, not allowed to depend on $n$, the series will usually diverge. Here's a sketch of the argument.

First, we can asymptotically evaluate the product $$P := \prod_{k=i}^{n-1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{1 + (k+1)\log(k+1)} \right)$$
as $i,n \rightarrow \infty$.

We take the logarithm of both sides and then expand the logs on the right side in power series to get $$\log P = \sum_{k=i}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1 + (k+1)\log(k+1)} + O \left(\frac{1}{i} \right),$$ say. We can replace the sum by an integral at the cost of the same error (see Lemma 2 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/254a-notes-1-elementary-multiplicative-number-theory/), for instance), so we have
$$\log P = \int_i^{n-1} \frac{1}{1 + (t+1)\log(t+1)} dt + O \left(\frac{1}{i} \right).$$ The error in replacing $\frac{1}{1 + (t+1)\log(t+1)}$ by $\frac{1}{(t+1)\log(t+1)}$ is negligible, and performing the integration gives
$$\log P = \log \log n - \log \log(i+1) + O(i^{-1})$$.

Therefore, the sum in question is equal to
$$\log n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \frac{1}{(1+(i+1)\log(i+1))\log(i+1)} \left(1 + O \left(\frac{1}{i} \right) \right).$$
The series
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i \log^2 i}$$
converges, so the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \frac{1}{(1+(i+1)\log(i+1))\log(i+1)} \left(1 + O \left(\frac{1}{i} \right) \right)$$
converges since $x_i \rightarrow 0$. Unless you can rig the $x_i$ to make the sum zero, your original sum will diverge as $n \rightarrow \infty$.